# How to use Google Assistant voice as Text to Speech

Tags: text, speech, assistant

Hi is there any way of using Google Assistant as a Text to Speech and output mp3 file.

I know of CLOUD TEXT-TO-SPEECH program, but I want to use Google assistant's new voice which is more clear and realistic

thanks in advance

Comment: should specify more technically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510129/android-text-to-speech-api-sounds-robotic/51612294#51612294